# Laravel 4 Queue Taking Long Time

Tags: laravel-4, queue, iron.io

I'm using iron.io for Queues in Laravel. They were working great until recently. Now a line of code like this one takes an eternity:

```
$sec = 5*60;
Queue::later($sec, 'MyClass@fire', ['id' => 1]);
```

`MyClass->fire` sends a bunch of emails so it's almost like it's sending the emails rather than sending the request to iron.io. But it's not. I removed all of the code in `MyClass->fire` and it still takes about 30s. But when I comment out `Queue::later(...` it runs really quickly.

It's like there's something wrong with `Queue` class. Or there's something wrong with the way my server communicates with iron.io.

Or maybe something wrong with the package I'm using. I know that it's really old (I think I'm using [iron_mq](https://packagist.org/packages/iron-io/iron_mq) v 1.3.0.) so maybe something has changed with the way the package I'm using works with iron.io. I'll try updating it in the morning but that might mess everything up.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'm from Iron.io Customer Success; I'm sorry you are having issues. Please email us at support@iron.io and we can pull up your account, and will troubleshoot the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There could be issues at 2 stages, that would need to be debugged.. 1) If the version of ironmq client and server are same, if not if there a change in way they communicate (I would say this is most important to debug) 2) If calling latter triggers a queue in ironmq, is the call received in ironmq and it is taking longer to respond..

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to network issues while connecting to IronMQ clusters. I checked the latency for two public clusters ([us-east-1](https://mq-aws-us-east-1-1.iron.io) and [eu-west-1](https://mq-aws-eu-west-1-1.iron.io)) and it takes less than 1 sec now.